# Set property in constructor definition

Tags: c#

**Note: I don't want to use records.**

In the newer versions of C#, Is there any way to set properties in constructor definition like other languages such as Dart or Typescript?

Example :

```
 public class Person
 {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
 }
```

In constructor instead of :

```
 public Person(string firstName, string lastName){
          FirstName = firstName;
          LastName  = lastName;
 }
```

Is there any feature like the following?

```
public Person(string this.FirstName, string this.LastName){
   
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at [record types in C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) - it looks like you'd want `public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);` (That's actually one of the specific examples...)

Comment: The documentation describes all the features in the language. Please feel free to post a question if you need help with a specific feature, but it's not very useful to ask the community to read the documentation for you. That said, as noted above, the new `record` type in C# will provide a much more concise way of declaring and using simple "data container" objects. See duplicates.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I am familiar with records

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sure, but didn't know what to search. I tried different search terms but did not get the answer. The article for constructors in C# in MS docs was dated back to 2017

Comment: _"The article for constructors in C# in MS docs was dated back to 2017"_ -- I'm not seeing how that's material. If there are no new changes to constructor, why would they update the article? You can find all the new features in recent versions here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9. You can read about _all_ of the language features in the documentation. If it's not there, the language doesn't have that feature. The new `record` type is the closest thing to what you're asking about, so if that's not what you want, the short answer to your question is "no".

Comment: @nAviD: If you're familiar with records, which is the most obvious way of doing what you've asked for, you should say that in the question - along with what it *doesn't* do that you want. Note that the article I linked to also shows initialization with tuples, e.g. `public Person(string firstName, string lastName) => (FirstName, LastName) = (firstName, lastName);`. If your question is really "does C# provide *exactly* the syntax I've asked for" then the answer is no, but that's not as interesting a question as "what facilities does C# provide for brevity in this area".

Comment: I found this question useful. The wording is not the same as any of the posted duplicates, and the proposed solution `go look at docs for something called records` is not obvious, especially for those of us coming from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Great news stay tuned for C# 12 which Include this feature called [Primary Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors) in a preview

> Primary constructor parameters are in scope throughout the class or struct declaration, and if they are captured by a function member or anonymous function, they are appropriately stored (e.g. as unspeakable private fields of the declared class or struct)

> The trade-off is that any other constructors must call through the primary constructor

```cs
class Person(string firstName, string lastName = "")
{
    public string FullName => $"{firstName} {lastName}";
}
```

```cs
var p = new Person("ibram" , "reda"); // optional last name
Console.WriteLine(p.FullName); // output: ibram reda
```

### Old Answer

You could use [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) syntax without any constructor implementation to define a public filed at instantiation like the following

```cs
var p = new Person{
      FirstName="anyName",
      LastName ="lastName"
};
```

if the person class is **immutable** then you would use [Record types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) from C# 9.0 as follwing

```
public record  Person(string FirstName, string LastName);

var p= new Person("firstName","LastName");
Consle.WriteLine(p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName);
```

You could only initialize a class through constructor or/and object initializer, and constructors does not support implicit initialization or declaration, so you have to write all things.